# Intermittent crash when performing fetch on core data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, crash-reports

I have a published app that is occasionally crashing when performing a core data fetch. I know where the crashes are occurring, however I can't figure out why they are happening.

The app uses a tab view controller, and the crash occurs in a tab that has a tableView as the initial view. Because I need this tableView to update whenever data is changed elsewhere in the app, I'm performing a fetch in the viewWillAppear method.

Here is the relevant code:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Day> = {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Day> = Day.fetchRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "calories > %@", "0")

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc
}()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch results")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And here is an image of the call stack.

[image: call stack]

I haven't been able to recreate the crash on my device or on the simulator, so I really don't know how to go about fixing this bug. I'd appreciate any advice on solving this.

Here's a screenshot of the `calories` attribute in the core data model.

[image]

Here's the class method for creating a `Day` entity.

```
    class func dayWithInfo(date: Date, inManagedContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Day {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .full
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Day> = Day.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateString = %@", dateString)

    if let day = (try? context.fetch(request))?.first {
        if let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date()) {
            // Update the macro goals if the date is the current or future date
            if date > yesterday {
                day.proteinGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.proteinValueKey)
                day.carbohydrateGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.carbohydratesValueKey)
                day.lipidGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.lipidsValueKey)
                day.fiberGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.fiberValueKey)
                day.calorieGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.caloriesValueKey)
            }
        }

        return day
    } else {
        let day = Day(context: context)

        // Set the date as a string representation of a day
        day.dateString = dateString
        day.date = date

        // Set the calorie and macronutrient goals from user defaults
        day.proteinGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.proteinValueKey)
        day.carbohydrateGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.carbohydratesValueKey)
        day.lipidGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.lipidsValueKey)
        day.fiberGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.fiberValueKey)
        day.calorieGoal = defaults.double(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.caloriesValueKey)

        // Creat meals and add their ralationship to the day
        if let meals = defaults.array(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.meals) as? [String] {
            for (index, name) in meals.enumerated() {
                _ = Meal.mealWithInfo(name: name, day: day, slot: index, inManagedContext: context)
            }
        }
        return day
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your `calories` column nullable perhaps? It appears your comparison predicate is failing when it tries to compare an object that doesn't implement the selector.

Comment: The calories attribute is given a default value, so it shouldn't ever be nil, but you're right, the problem does appear to be with the comparison predicate.

Comment: What's the type for the `calories` attribute?

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is for your crash but from the documentation for `viewWillAppear`, _"If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation."_

Comment: The type of `calories` is Double. I'll look into calling super on `viewWillAppear`, but I'm thinking a different approach might be in order, especially if I can't get to the bottom of this crash. I use the app myself everyday and I've never had it crash on me.

Comment: Is `calories` an optional attribute? If so, it's possible that at some point there was a way to save an entity without one, even though you think you're always setting a default value. Do you implement a validation method on your entity, for example, so that you _know_ it can never be successfully saved without a proper value?

Comment: Further question... when you say that you're setting a default value, is this configured on the model attribute (so that Core Data manages the default) or are you setting the default value in your own code?

Comment: No, the `calories` attribute isn't optional and it's set to 0 in the model. I'll add a screenshot of the relevant core data model to the post.

Comment: Well that shoots _that_ theory. :P

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a validation method for the entity, but I'll add the class method used to create the `Day` entity to my post.

Comment: Core data automatically tries to call methods with a signature like validate<attribute> (validateCalories, in your case) to do attribute level validation before saving the entity. I have the full method syntax in my answer below, even though the rest of it is rubbish now. Returning false from such a method will cause the save to fail. It doesn't sound like this is your issue, though.

Comment: You've seen this a few times, so is there any pattern in `Hardware Model` or `OS Version` in the crash report?

Comment: Mostly in iOS 11.4, but a couple in 11.3 and 11.2. There have been no crashes in 10.x. The highest iOS my device can run is 10.3.3, so I can't test the app in 11.x on a device. Of course I don't know if the crashes occurring only on devices running 11.x is just a coincidence or not. My user base isn't that large.

Comment: Yeah, just looking for commonalities that might point to something we're missing. You've run though those OS versions on the simulator and can't replicate the crash?

Comment: Would you mind posting a representative crash report?

Comment: I'd be glad to, but I don't see a way to download them or print them out. The screenshot I added is from the one I have opened in Xcode now.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `NSPredicate(format: "calories > %@", "0")` rather than simply `calories > 0`? By using the object reference syntax, you're creating a string and using that string to compare with a double value.

Comment: I thought that was the way `NSPredicate` needed to be formatted. I'll look into it though.

Comment: Predicate specifiers: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html. In essence you're creating a string and then that string is replaced in the predicate by calling descriptionWithLocale: or description:. While that _should_ work, I wonder if there are some edge cases. Since you know your attribute is a double, you could use the `NSPredicate(format: "calories > %f", 0.0)`, but it really just adds parsing overhead. I'm not a Swift guy, but I think `NSPredicate(format: "calories > 0")` should work.

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "calories > 0")` seems to work fine. I don't know if the other way of doing it has anything to do with the crashes, but I'm going to include the more straight forward way in my next update and see how it goes.

Comment: Perfect. The frustrating thing is that I can't say _for certain_ that it had anything to do with the crashes, but since all signs point to the predicate being the cause, it's a good approach. I hope it solves it for you.

Comment: I wanted to follow up on this. It looks like changing the predicate fixed the problem. Since the update I have had zero user crashes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to posit a *theory* about what I think is happening. I might be making incorrect assumptions about your project, so please correct anything I get wrong. You likely understand all the below, but I'm trying to be thorough, so please excuse anything obvious.

You have a `calories` attribute of your model class that is implemented as an optional attribute with no default *at the model level*. Something like the below.

[image: Optional attribute]

You also do not implement `func validateCalories(calories: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool` in your managed object subclass, so it's *possible* to save an instance with a nil (remember that Core Data is still Objective-C, so your Double Swift attribute is an NSNumber in Core Data, so nil is perfectly valid for an optional attribute).

> You can specify that an attribute is optional — that is, it is not required to have a value. In general, however, you are discouraged from doing so — especially for numeric values (typically you can get better results using a mandatory attribute with a default value — in the model — of 0). The reason for this is that SQL has special comparison behavior for NULL that is unlike Objective-C's nil. NULL in a database is not the same as 0, and searches for 0 will not match columns with NULL.

At this point, it would be easy to confirm the hypothesis. Simply edit the SQLite database used for Core Data by your app in the simulator and set the `calories` attribute of a single record to `null` and see if you crash in the same way.

If so, do a Core Data migration on your next release and remove the `Optional` designation on the model attribute and provide a `Default` value of zero.

Comment: That would make sense if I were using optionals, but I've set the attribute to a default value. Would `func validateCalories(calories: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool` still have any relevance if I'm not using optionals? That's not an area of core data that I've looked into.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it would help, given the new information you've provided. I was making a lot of assumptions in the hope of getting to a solution quicker. The validation method is probably not going to add anything in your case, as it appears you've done all you can to setup the model properly. That being said, it still appears that a predicate is at fault. You're sure that both your `date` and `calories` attributes have been required and properly defaulted from the first version of your app?

Comment: Absolutely. Nothing regarding core data has changed since the fist published version of the app.